# One Signal V5 Template ID is null

Tags: flutter, push-notification, notifications, onesignal, flutter-notification

I am sending a push notification to my Flutter app from a Template in the One Signal dashboard. Using the OSNotification class from the Flutter Onesignal package I am easily able to get the notification title. However, the template Id, which is supposed to be available within OSNotification class is null. Please see photo:

[image: VS Code Console]
I tried to print the OneSignal TemplateID to the console. The notification title prints, but the template ID is null.

Here is my Template in the dashboard. You can see the templateId in the url, which should be displaying in the VS Code console.

[image: One Signal Template in Dashboard]

I could use the Notification Title to do the logic of what I want to happen upon receiving the notification, however it would be much cleaner to do it by the unique id which should be available.